# Matplotlib set minor ticks by default "ON"

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way I can set minor ticks "ON" by default, for example using "rcsettings.py" (in Enthought Python, equivalent to matplotlibrc)?
I have matplotlib-1.3.1-3 installed

Comment: wait, what? enthought mangles the rcparam system?

Comment: I could find rcsettings.py file under my canopy installation as 
~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsettings.py

Comment: you should not be editing parts of the installed library.  Please see http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html  What version of mpl are you using?

Comment: And in any case, I could not find an rcparam to do this.

Comment: Edited my original discription

Answer (score 2):

Finally the problem is solved in Matplotlib version 1.5.0-1, I recently updated the matplotlib. Once you update the Matplotlib (either manually or through EPD package manager). Find the file called rcsetup.py. Usually on windows you can find it at

`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py`

DO NOT edit the original file. Make a copy of the original file and rename it as OriginalRCsetup.py. Now open the file named `rcsetup.py` and search for line containing parameter `xtick.minor.visible` and edit it as `True`

```
#Leave a comment there, edited by me
'xtick.minor.visible':   [True, validate_bool],    # visiablility of the x axis minor ticks
```

similarly, find and edit ytick.minor.visible.

```
#Leave a comment there, edited by me
'ytick.minor.visible':   [True, validate_bool],    # visiablility of the x axis minor ticks
```

Save the file and restart the python interpreter.

Comment: This is an unusable solution: hacking into the source code. There should be another way. This won't work if run on other machines or if you update matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.rcParams['xtick.minor.visible'] = True
```

And some more parameters to modify the strange matplotlib defaults:

```
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 16
plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = True
plt.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'in'
plt.rcParams['xtick.minor.size'] = 4
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 8
plt.rcParams['xtick.minor.visible'] = True
```